# .render function is running but not setting anything

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm playing around with Backbone.js for the first time, and I'm having a bit of trouble.
My initial intention was to show the content of a certain slide, but I've fallen back to 'just trying to display anything' with the .text() method.

My render method get's called, I can see that in the log, but the 'currentslide' id is not filled. Does anyone know what silly thing I'm overlooking here?

Seeing as the Backbone code seems to do ok, it might be a jQuery related issue. I'm pretty new to both of them.

Many thanks in advance,

Dieter

This is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Presentation</title>

<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="js/slides.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="slideshow">
      <h2 id="currentslide"></h2>
</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And this is my Backbone code so far:

```
(function($) {

window.Slide = Backbone.Model.extend({
    content: "Testcontent",
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('Slide created');
    }
});

window.Slidedeck = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Slide,   
});

window.Slideshow = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#slideshow'),
    currentSlide: 0,

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },  
    render: function (){
        console.log('Rendering');

        $('#currentslide').text('This aint even working darned.');
        return this;
    }

});

var slidedeck = new Slidedeck([
    new Slide({
        content: "Slide 1",
    }),
    new Slide({
        content: "Slide 2",
    }),
]);

var slideshow = new Slideshow({
    collection: slidedeck,
});

slideshow.render();

})(jQuery);
```

EDIT:
I tried the suggestion to replace the last line of code with

```
$(slideshow.render().el).appendTo('body');
```

But that doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

The weird thing is that I have another piece of code with a render() where the .text() works perfectly.

```
render: function (){
$('#actionValue').text(this.model.get('value'));
return this;
}
```

Since the render() code gets run on both pieces of code, I assume it has nothing to do with binding anything.
But for some reason the latter does its .text() just fine, the first one does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the element `#slideshow` already exists in your HTML, so you don't need to append it to the body as specified in @czarchaic's answer.

You're having issues because you're attempting to render and set the value of `#slideshow` before it exists in the DOM.  This happens because you've included `js/slides.js` before the DOM elements are created.  The JS is included and executed, but when `slideshow.render()` is called, the `#slideshow` element has not yet been created, so `$('#slideshow')` will return no elements, thus `text()` is doing nothing.

You need to either...

1. Move your JavaScript include to after the DOM elements creation

   ```
   <!doctype html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">

   <title>Presentation</title>

   <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/vendor/underscore.js"></script>
   <script src="js/vendor/backbone.js"></script>
   // Remove the include from here
   </head>

   <body>
     <div id="container">
       <div id="slideshow">
         <h2 id="currentslide"></h2>
       </div>
     </div>
   </body>

   // Put it here
   <script src="js/slides.js"></script>
   ```
2. Or you need to wrap your `render` call in a document ready block

   ```
   (function($) {

   window.Slide = Backbone.Model.extend({ ... });

   window.Slidedeck = Backbone.Collection.extend({ ... });

   window.Slideshow = Backbone.View.extend({ ... });

   var slidedeck = new Slidedeck([ ... ]);

   var slideshow = new Slideshow({ ... });

   // Don't render until the elements exist
   $(slideshow.render);

   })(jQuery);
   ```

Comment: kpeel, you are an absolute life saver. I spend hours looking at that small piece of code, pulling my hair out :-) Figures it was a 'document ready' thingy.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Once you render you need to do something with the return object. In this case it's the Slideshow view.

```
$( slideshow.render().el ).appendTo( 'body' );
```

Your view's render function returns itself so target the builtin `el` property

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it doesn't seem to change anything though. 
I edited the question with an extra piece of info on a piece of code that does work, weirdly.